# Partial text search with postgreql & django

Tags: django, postgresql, full-text-search

Tried to implement partial text search with postgresql and django,used the following query

```
Entry.objects.filter(headline__contains="search text")
```

This returns records having exact match,ie suppose checking for a match against the record "welcome to the new world" with query __contains="welcome world" , returns zero records

How can i implement this partial text search with postgresql-8.4 and django?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7aPnE5gF

Answer (score 2):

If you want this exact partial search you can use the **startswitch** field lookup method: Entry.objects.filter(headline__startswith="search text"). See more info at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#startswith.

This method creates a LIKE query ("*SELECT ... WHERE headline LIKE 'search text%'*") so if you're looking for a fulltext alternative you can check out PostgreSQL's built in [Tsearch2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tsearch2.html) extension or other options such as [Xapian](http://xapian.org/), [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/), etc.

Each of the former engines mentioned have Django apps that makes them easier to integrate: [Djapian](https://code.google.com/p/djapian/) for Xapian integration or [Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/) for multiple integrations in one app.